# css class to lighten background color

Tags: css

I need a class that lightens the elements background color without specifying the color in the class.

It's easy when I hard code the color:

```
.lighten {
    background-color: lighten(blue, 30%)
}
```

But how can I apply lighten to whatever color the element has without affecting the content color?

```
<div class="blue lighten">
 <div>
    content color should not be affected
 </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ozpzew

Comment: Would setting on opacity give you the result you want?  I think it would also lighten the forground / text though but might be suitable?  

`.lighten { opacity: 0.6 }`

Comment: Have you considered using something like a *pseudo-element*, taken out of the normal document flow (with `position: absolute`), with an `opacity` property rule applied, that acts as an "overlay" of the element in question?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError i was going to implement this right now ;)

Comment: Go for it Temani :) @TemaniAfif

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError you got it first so do it and you will get my upvote ;)

Comment: in addtion to what @UncaughtTypeError said i would consider also filter and not only opacity that you can easily apply on the pseudo element without affecting the main content

Comment: I'm going to pass on this one, I feel using a *pseudo-element* would require a demonstration, and there is not enough to go off on here, for example; I can't account for any nested elements and stacking context will most likely be an issue in that case.

Comment: I have added a codepen. feel free to experiment. I have not found a proper solution (absolute positioning is probably the right way, but I have not managed to make it work yet)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

```
.lighten {
   filter: brightness(150%);
}
```

Change the % to fit your needs

Comment: This also affects the contents (i.e. text color)

Comment: @Chris note that you didn't specify that if your first question version...