# css absolute position blocks text selection

Tags: css

How can I make the text selectable? I have already tried it with z-index

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.lighten {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  this text cannot be selected
  <div class="absolute blue lighten">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ozpzew

Comment: I thought you may experience issues with stacking contexts. Consider wrapping text with elements that can be attributed higher `z-index` property values.

Comment: Do you need the opacity to always apply the the text?

Comment: @Pangloss I actually used the relative/absolute divs to prevent the text from being affected by the opacity setting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable pointer events on absolutely positioned element and it will allow you to select text behind it

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.lighten {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  this text can now be selected
  <div class="absolute blue lighten">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or auto to re-enable say ex. for children.

Answer (score 1):

Give the positioned element `z-index: -1`.

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.lighten {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  this text cannot be selected
  <div class="absolute blue lighten">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What did I miss?

Comment: don't know, it's also a good solution, which works, but maybe it can then misbehave with other CSS objects due to negative z-index. anyways, I'll upvote you :)

Comment: This question is kind of open-ended. There are many ways to highlight the text. Alter the HTML, `pointer-events`, `z-index` and more. Considering the details available, there are many possible solutions.

Comment: that's absolutely true, I just prefer pointer-events because I often alter z-index values on elements. advantage of z-index is for example having the text highlight with correct colour, but maybe it's a disadvantage to someone, as it also leaves default text colour (while with overlay without z-index, it should mix overlay and text colours)

Comment: This question has come off the result of a previously posted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48009479/css-class-to-lighten-background-color#48009479 So the overlay is being used as a mechanism to "lighten" the background colour. To be fair, the OP should clarify that in the problem statement.

Comment: OK, so negative z-index should be the answer